# Как убрать отступы между SVG элементами?

Tags: svg, отступы, padding

Добрый день уважаемые. Столкнулся с непониманием откуда берутся отступы между SVG элементами и как от них избавится ?

```css
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  .row{
   width: 100px;
   height: 1000px;
   background: linear-gradient(to top, red, blue);
  }
  svg, rect, mask, circle{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
     <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
   </svg>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
     <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
   </svg>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
     <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
   </svg>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
     <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
   </svg>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
     <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
   </svg>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
     <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
   </svg>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
     <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
   </svg>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
     <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
   </svg>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
     <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
   </svg>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
     <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
   </svg>
  </div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю избавиться от процентов в маске и в других элементах, так будет легче разобраться, что и откуда берется. Проценты, конечно дело хорошее в верстке, но в учебном примере лучше без них обойтись. Для этого переходим на другую модель маски. Используем текущую систему координат элемента, к которому применяется маска.

```
<mask id="circles" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
```

Для сокращения кода не повторяем 10 раз SVG код, а собираем всё в один файл.
Маску определяем в секции `<defs>... </defs>` один раз

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.row{
  width: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, red, blue);
}
svg, rect, mask, circle{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
       <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 100 1000"> 
<defs>
 <mask id="circles" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <g stroke="gray" stroke-width="4" fill="white">
      <rect  width="100" height="1000" fill="white"></rect>
  <g fill="black">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="150" r="45" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="250" r="45" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="350" r="45" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="450" r="45" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="550" r="45" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="650" r="45" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="750" r="45" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="850" r="45" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="950" r="45" />
  </g>
      </g>
   </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="1000" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>     
 </svg>
   
  </div>
```

Теперь можно гибко регулировать расстояние между кругами.
Возможно при дальнейшем изучении вы столкнетесь с другой проблемой отступов SVG изображений при внедрении последних в текстовую страничку. Как бороться с отступами в этом случае подробно написано в этой [статье](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1204)

Answer (score 5):

```
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.row{
  width: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, red, blue);
}
svg, rect, mask, circle{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" style="mask: url(#circles)"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

PS: И вообще, я же давал [ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/613191/178988) с одним svg.

Comment: Спасибо, был не внимателен. А из-за чего они появляться эти отступы, и зачем в таком случае ещё и ширина задается? Какай  display по умолчанию у SVG ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991, дефаултный display - это `inline-block`, у которого `vertical-align: baseline`. Соответственно, всё пространство между базовой линией и низом остаётся пустым. Никакую ширину я не трогал и не понял, о чём вопрос.